# Ruby on rails : associations with multiple columns on non id key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I try to implement a simple app where I have users and I get the users friendships from a social network. I have two models with the following columns:

`User` :

- `id` (the default id)
- `sn_id` (the id from the user in the social network)

`FriendsRelation` :

- `user1_sn_id` (foreign key to `User.sn_id`)
- `user2_sn_id` (foreign key to `User.sn_id`)

How to implement the associations?

for now I wrote on users :

```
has_many :friends1, :class_name =>"FriendsRelation", :foreign_key =>"user1_sn_id"
has_many :friends2, :class_name =>"FriendsRelation", :foreign_key =>"user2_sn_id"
```

The problem is that if I want to get all the friends of a user, I have to use `u.friends1` and `u.friends2` but how do I get rid of the dissymetry?

And what associations should I put on FriendsRelation?

Also, the user ids in the FriendsRelation table are those from the social network because it is easier for me. Is it a problem? Should I put the user id instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your own `id` instead of the primery key is not a problem. Only make sure that there are no duplications and add an index to that column as well.

Regarding the dissimetry you have multiple solutions:

- Merging the two list based on the two ids e.g. `def friends; friends1 + friends2; end`
- Adding double records (both ways) to the friends table
- Specifying custom scopes for the relations to reflect the relationship from the right point of view

All have pros and cons, but all are valid solutions AFAIK.

Comment: Ok but how to specify the relation so that it uses sn_id instead of od? I can't do something like this : `has_many :friends1, :class_name =>"FriendsRelation", :foreign_key =>"user1_sn_id", :key =>"sn_id"`

Comment: Use `:association_foreign_key => "sn_id"`